# How can i catch the route change?

Tags: svelte, router, onbeforeunload

I use '**tinro'** for routing at svelte.

I can catch the change in the window with the 'beforeunload' method. (shutdown, manual url change, window or browser closing). But when I want to change page by clicking on the links I created with 'tinro', I can't catch 'beforeunload'. How can i solve this ?

If there are changes in the form page in the project, if the route is wanted to be changed or if the url path is wanted to be changed, I need to capture this within the page.

Answer (score 2):

this is what you need everytime the route changes `onRouteChange` will be called:

add to layouts.svelte:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { navigating } from '$app/stores';

$: if($navigating) onRouteChange();
</script>
```

Comment: In my case this event was triggered **before** navigating. I used `$page`, which was triggered when the navigation completed

Answer (score 0):

According to the package documentation You can make use of the [router subscribe method](https://github.com/AlexxNB/tinro#routersubscribefunc). The router object is a valid Svelte store, so you can subscribe to get the changing navigation data.

```js
import { router } from 'tinro';

const currentpath = String($router.url);
// subscribe to the route changes
router.subscribe((nextRoute) => {
    // if the user is navigating away from the current page
    if (nextRoute.url !== currentpath) {
        try {
            // if the form was modified show confirmation dialog
            if (JSON.stringify(form) !== JSON.stringify(resetForm)) {
                // if the user clicked cancel stay in the same page
                if(window.confirm("Are you sure you want to exit without saving?") == false)
                    throw new Error();
                // else (user clicked ok) continue navigation to the next route
            }

        } catch (error) {
            // return to current page. In other words stay in the same page
            router.goto(currentpath);
        }
    }
});
```